# Is it true to say that machine languages have some degree of abstraction?

Tags: computation-models, abstract-data-types

I think anyone would agree that assembly languages ("threshold languages") have some very little abstraction but is it true to say that also machine languages have some degree of abstraction?

Comment: There used to be a somewhat useful translator from Intel 8080/8085 assembly to 8086 - assembly, not machine language, far as memory serves. And from 8008 to 8080, at that.

Comment: What do you mean with "threshold languages" ??

Comment: "some degree of abstraction" is way too vague to allow an answer.

Comment: Anyway, is it clear that there is a degree of abstraction, in range $[0,100\%]$.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you consider the most non-abstracted.

Memory addresses get translated from the virtual address space to physical RAM address space through the page table.

The instruction set can address a number of registers, however in many CPUs there are more register locations available in the register file than can be addressed by the machine code. In the back end there is a register renaming mechanism to map the instruction register to the actual bit of SRAM in the register file.

Out of Order CPUs don't execute the instructions in order (it's kinda in the name), instead it only pretends to do so and instead shuffles around actual execution in the functional units as the results of previous instructions become available to execute upon.